# Classic childrens books that are unknown outside of DE/AT/CH?

Tags: learning, book, big-list

> **This question is present as a matter of historical interest.  While you are encouraged to help maintain its answers, please understand that "big list" questions are not generally allowed on German Language and Usage and will be closed per the [FAQ](https://german.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).**

What are the German language equivalents of Enid Blyton, Roald Dahl etc?

Books that are so good that kids long to read them, doesn't matter which age range.

I'd immediately ignore "Emil and the Detectives" and "Heidi" as these are very well known tales.

Comment: Enid Blyton is actually quite popular in Germany as well, so it's not that good an example if you're looking for regional children's literature ;)

Comment: Since this is a "big list" type of question, I suggest community wiki and one answer per post. Feel free to disagree. :)

Comment: Actually this is kind of a hard question. It's difficult to judge what's known outside one's country, not only when it comes to books but also music, movies etc.

Comment: @ladybug: At least from an English speaker's point of view, if you can buy a 'normal' copy of a book (not a special import) or if a non DE wikipedia article exists for a book then I'd assume it's probably reasonably well known.

Comment: @OregonGhost: the themes and language will be of British origin so won't be a true 'German Language' book. See here for example: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-13545386

Comment: Although the viewpoints in the article are a bit too extreme IMO - there *is* small talk in German everyday life, too - it is *fascinating* reading. Bookmarking, thanks for this.

Comment: Du fragst nach Büchern und bringst Autoren als Beispiele?

Answer (score 19):

Der Autor [Otfried Preußler](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otfried_Preu%C3%9Fler) hat eine Reihe von exzellenten Kinderbüchern verfasst, u. a.

- Der kleine Wassermann
- Die kleine Hexe
- Der Räuber Hotzenplotz
- Das kleine Gespenst
- Krabat

Comment: +1 für den kleinen Wassermann.

Comment: Just want to add that "Krabat" is not for little children. It's quite different from his other books in that way.

Comment: And one of the lesser-known but not to be neglected Preussler characters is *Hörbe mit dem großen Hut*.

Answer (score 18):

I'd say that all Michael Ende books except "The Neverending Story" satisfies your criteria (because "The Neverending Story" is too well known). At least in Norway "Momo" and "Jim Knopf und Lukas der Lokomotivführer" are largely unheard of.

Comment: The Neverending Story is a must... I need to read it, I only saw the old movie :D

Comment: Other lovely books by Michael Ende are: "Das Traumfresserchen", "Der Lindwurm und der Schmetterling oder Der seltsame Tausch" and "Der satanarchäolügenialkohöllische Wunschpunsch".

Comment: I agree with "Momo" specifically and Michael Ende generally since my German speaking friends always made these exact recommendations when I asked this question.

Answer (score 12):

[Christine Nöstlinger](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christine_N%C3%B6stlinger) is an award winning author children books. I remember being read a translation of "Wir pfeifen auf den Gurkenkönig" and enjoying it immensely.

Answer (score 11):

Even though "Emil und die Detektive" may be well-known outside of Germany (didn't even know that until now ^^), some of [Erich Kästner](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_K%C3%A4stner)'s other children's books might be not:

- Das fliegende Klassenzimmer
- Die Konferenz der Tiere
- Der kleine Mann
- Der kleine Mann und die kleine Miss
- Der 35. Mai oder Konrad reitet in die Südsee

The last three were among my favourite books as a kid. ;-)

Comment: "Die Konferenz der Tiere" wurde kürzlich erst verfilmt.

Comment: For some unknown reason, only EATD is known.

Comment: What about "Das doppelte Lottchen"? Haven't mentioned it because I guessed it didn't match your criteria.

Comment: Don't forget "Pünktchen und Anton". Had this as an audio drama on cassette and loved it as a child. I still know the prologue by heart. Kästner considered this his best children's book.

Comment: @ladybug Don't know how (un-)known "Das doppelte Lottchen" actually is outside Germany - but at least it didn't escape the attention of the Disney studios. The German title of that movie version is ["Die Vermähling ihrer Eltern geben bekannt"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Verm%C3%A4hlung_ihrer_Eltern_geben_bekannt)

Answer (score 10):

Well known in Germany but almost unknown elsewhere are the stories about the *Sams* by [Paul Maar](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Maar).

The first three books *"Eine Woche voller Samstage"*, *"Am Samstag kam das Sams zurück"*, and *"Neue Punkte für das Sams"* are great fun reading.

For non-native readers the ambiguous usage of language by the *Sams* may be a challenge.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend [Wilhelm Busch - Max und Moritz](http://www.wilhelm-busch-seiten.de/werke/maxundmoritz/vorwort.html). I can still recite most of the book word for word.

Answer (score 7):

I'd also like to mention "Vom kleinen Maulwurf, der wissen wollte, wer ihm auf den Kopf gemacht hat." which is one of the more odd childrens books.

Comment: Definitely +1 for this one.

Comment: A cool book for the anal stage, but note that this is for very young children.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of well-known children's books by Mira Lobe, in particular "Bimbulli" and "Das kleine Ich-bin-Ich".  (In sharp contrast to modern children's series that aim to sell a lot of merchandise, these books include a set of instructions to the parents to actually sew the main character for their children.)

Age: 5-7

Answer (score 4):

If **comics and illustrated stories** count I’d like to add some (from the past 40ish years), most of which also come as movies, TV series or audio plays and as toy merchandise:

- [*Struwwelpeter*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struwwelpeter) by Heinrich Hoffmann – a cruel classic.
- [*Oh, wie schön ist Panama*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh,_wie_sch%C3%B6n_ist_Panama) and other stories by Janosch – You can hardly consider yourself German if you don’t know what a *Tigerente* is (except if you’re old).
- [*Freunde, Mullewapp, Tabaluga, Sauerkraut*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freunde_(Kinderbuch)) and other books by Helme Heine
- [*Werner*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_(Comic)) by Röttger „Brösel“ Feldmann – It’s a challenge due to written (Northern) dialects, and not that suitable for younger kids.
- [*Käpt’n Blaubär*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4pt%E2%80%99n_Blaub%C3%A4r), [*Das Kleine Arschloch*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_Kleine_Arschloch) and other stories (for older kids and grown-ups) by Walter Moers
- [*Fix und Foxi*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fix_und_Foxi) by Rolf Kauka
- [*Ritter Rost*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritter_Rost) by Jörg Hilbert / Felix Janas; includes music.
- [*Urmel* stories](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urmel_aus_dem_Eis) by Max Kruse. The puppet version by Augsburger Puppenkiste actually may be better known than the books.
- [*Pumuckl*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meister_Eder_und_sein_Pumuckl) by Ellis Kaut. The original radio plays and television series are more popular, though.
- [*Benjamin Blümchen*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Bl%C3%BCmchen) and [*Bibi Blocksberg*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibi_Blocksberg) by Elfie Donnelly (who’s actually British). These are mostly known from audio plays.
- [*Ein Fall für TKKG*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/TKKG) by Rolf Kalmuczak. Also maybe better known from the audio plays.
- [*Prinzessin Lillifee*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prinzessin_Lillifee) by Monika Finsterbusch – pink as hell, like German *Hello Kitty*
- [*Käpt’n Sharky*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4pt%E2%80%99n_Sharky) by Jutta Langreuter / Silvio Neuendorf – male counterpart to Lillie
- [*Die Olchis*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Olchis) by Erhard Dietl
- [*Biene Maja*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biene_Maja) originally books by Walter Bonsels, but most only know the animated series – as a German you know the lyrics to the theme song.
- [*Wickie*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wickie_und_die_starken_M%C3%A4nner_(Kinderbuch)) by Runer Jonsson (who’s Swedish) – like Maja best know from a 1970s anime adaptation.
- [*Felix*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_(Kinderbuch-Serie)) by Annette Langen
- [*Bobo Siebenschläfer*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobo_Siebenschl%C3%A4fer) by Markus Osterwalder

Asterix, Lucky Luke and others may not be as well known in English-speaking countries, but are popular throughout Europe and they are not of German origin, but French/Belgian.

There’s also a variety of [*Wimmelbücher*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wimmelbilderbuch) (e.g. by Ali Mitgutsch) without text that are not as popular in other countries as far as I know, with the notable exception of *Where’s Wally?* (or *Waldo*). 
Likewise cheap 10 cm × 10 cm [*Pixi-Bücher*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixi-B%C3%BCcher) are well known among German children and parents. They feature some original characters like *Pixi*, *Conni* and *Petzi*, but also other better known stories that have been shortened or edited to fit the format.

### Recent book series, not comic

- [*Die Wilden Hühner*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Wilden_H%C3%BChner) by Cornelia Funke
- [*Die Wilden (Fußball-)Kerle*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Wilden_Fu%C3%9Fballkerle) by Joachim Masannek / Jan Birke

Answer (score 3):

Sigrid Heuck: Pony, Bär und Apfelbaum

A classic for very young children where part of the words are replaced by pictures so the small child can read part of the words. There are more books in this series.

Answer (score 2):

I also loved the books of [Peter Abraham](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Abraham) as a child (especially "Das Schulgespenst", "Der Affenstern" and "Weshalb bekommt man eine Ohrfeige?")

He was quite famous in the GDR, but apparently they aren't published any more. So that's even an insider in Germany itself. ;-)

Same is true for [Hannes Hüttner](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannes_H%C3%BCttner) ("Das Blaue vom Himmel"). Bit sad you can't get those books anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[Käthe Recheis: Der weiße Wolf](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3423702982)

A fantasy novel where the main character is summoned to a fantasy world to help the woodland tribes against the invaders.

Answer (score 1):

[Hohlbein: Elfentanz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3800053241)

A fantasy story where the main character fights against an evil black lord, but the ending is less black and white than one might expect.

Answer (score 1):

*Kleiner Eisbär* books by Hans de Beer are perfect for language learning. They are only 30 pages long and use simple vocabulary. Reading these books made me realize that I need to study more adverbs. *Bisa Bia, Bisa Bel*  by Ana Maria Machado was written by a Brazilian but it is unavailable in English. I've been slowly translating this book as a language learning exercise and I'll be the only English speaker to have read it when I'm done.

Answer (score 1):

Known in Switzerland

- Divico
- Die Kummerbuben
- Heidi und der Geissenpeter
- Wir Kinder aus Bullerbü (and everything else by Astrid Lindgren)
- Schellenursli
- Papa Moll
- Globi

Comment: Of course, Astrid Lindgren is neither Swiss nor German, but Swedish. Still great books (and movies) of course.